# Ubuntu: `env -i bash --norc`, but include essential variables such as HOME, DISPLAY? (where are these set?)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, environment-variables

Is there an easy way to isolate a session of bash so that only essential variables (`HOME`, `USER`, `DISPLAY`, etc.) are preserved? (essential in that many programs fail if HOME, DISPLAY, TERM, SHELL, etc. are not set).
Namely, does anyone know where these are set?

I had tried adding the line `test -n "${NO_ALIASES+D}" && return 0` to my `~/.bash_aliases` (I didn't do anything additional in `~/.bashrc`) so a pristine `~/.bashrc` would be sourced if I did

```
env -i NO_ALIASES=1 bash
```

but those variables were still missing.

I also tried source `/etc/profile` too in the isolated shell, but to no avail.

The one that does work is a manual pass-through:

```
env -i HOME=$HOME DISPLAY=$DISPLAY SHELL=$SHELL TERM=$TERM bash --norc
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Why do you need this? Which variables do you not want?

Comment: I want to work within the same user account but with the minimal set of environment variables, without having to manually switch around my environment itself.
I am working with ROS's [catkin build system](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/), which is an awesome tool (for doing stuff like cohesive workspaces and multiple builds, chaining workspace dependencies, path management). Within this system and ROS itself, there are a ton of environment variables, a lot of which are appended to, and some that may not go away by re-sourcing the setup files. I would like to reproduce results by isolating the env.